# How to write multiple rule in Htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter framework for my site and I have a blog site also which is done in wordpress. My site url is like this `https://mydomain.com` And my blog url is `https://mydomain.com/blog`. i have written htaccess for my site like this

`RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ index.php/profile/fundraiser/$1`

Whenever I take my blog site it always redirecting to profile controller(which is defined in htaccess). If the url is`https://mydomain/blog` it should redirect to my blog and in other cases it should redirect to profile controller. Can I write multiple Htaccess rule for this since I have put both files in the same domain?  Any one please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use Rewrite condition like bellow -

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(blog)
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ index.php/profile/fundraiser/$1
```

i.e. only when URL doesn't contain blog then it will redirect to the profile page. You can add more condition for each rule.